# HorizontalScrollView - how to move one item at a time

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I'm working with an horizontal scroll view composed of a maximum number of 10 Network Image View, added programmatically to the horizontal scroll view.

The problem I'm trying to figure out is simple.
My objective is to show one image at a time when the user scrolls the view.
Basically, I'd like to realize a slideshow similar to the app "AutoScout24".
I tried to add a Scroll Listener, but it doesn't behave as I wanted.

Thank you for your help.
If you need it, I may post the code of the listener.

EDIT:
That's the XML code, using the ViewPager.
I can't understand why if I put it inside a ScrollView, it shows nothing.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="AppInfo"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/bread" />


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/image_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/attivita_linear"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:isScrollContainer="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nome Attività"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_nome"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:paddingBottom="35dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Indirizzo:  "
                    android:id="@+id/textView_indirizzo"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Telefono:  "
                    android:id="@+id/textView_tel"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Email:  "
                    android:id="@+id/textView_email"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="www:  "
                    android:id="@+id/textView_www"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Descrizione:  "
                    android:id="@+id/textView_descrizione"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/attivita_buttons"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:isScrollContainer="true">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_button_call"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_call"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_button_share"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_share"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    />

                <!-- TODO implement Calendar button
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_call"/>

                -->

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cola">
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) does what you need, unless you can't use it.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying using it, but I can't figure out why it is not shown if I use it inside a ScrollView.

Comment: Check your logcat output.  You can't nest certain scrollable views inside other scrollable containers.  There will be an error in logcat.

Comment: you can view my answer here I just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799477/how-to-display-the-image-with-name-in-android/24799868#24799868

Comment: Yes, I've already implemented an adapter like that!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I decided to implement a ViewPager instead of HorizontalScrollView.

Thanks to the ImageAdapter, handling the scroll moves is