# how to display the image with name in android

Tags: android

Hi In My application I am displaying images by using swipe.Now, i want to display the under the image i want to display the name.

I want to write the some name in that image.how to write the code
Can anyone please help me.

**Photos class updated code**

```
    public class Photos extends Activity {

    Button button1;  
    String mImages;

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

          String[] description_images = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("{image1,image2,image3,image4}"); //ARRAY OF ALL TEXT ASSOCIATED TO IMAGES
          String[] mImages = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("{R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d}");  


       // String[] mText={"Text1","Text2","Text3"};

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view, null);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            final TextView textView = (TextView )view.findViewById(R.id.iv_text);

            textView.setText(description_images[position]);
           // imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            container.addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: You just need to crate one layout with top `TextView` and Center `ImageView` and inflate that Layout in your `instantiateItem(...)` method and set different values on it...

Comment: how to set the values

Comment: Fetch values as position from `Array` and set to your `View`. like i would say `imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position])` and also same for `TextView` like `text_View.setText(mText[position]);`

Comment: If i am creating array it showing error

Comment: @j What is that? post it

Comment: private int[] mText = new int[] {image1,
          image22,
         image3,
          image4 
      };

Comment: OMG!!! Are you a `Programmer`? create a `String Array` Like: `String[] mText={"Text1","Text2","Text3"};`

Answer (score 0):

```
    description_images = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("images_name"); //ARRAY OF ALL TEXT ASSOCIATED TO IMAGES
    mImages = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("images_path"); //ARRAY OF ALL IMAGE PATHS

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view, null);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            final TextView textView = (TextView )view.findViewById(R.id.iv_text);

            textView.setText(description_images[position]);
            imageLoader.displayImage(mImages[position], imageView, options);
            container.addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }
```

**Corresponding XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iv_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i want to create new xml?

Comment: so create it, i just provided

Comment: you can write here `imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);`

Comment: hi Nitin Misra can you please tell me

Comment: you can write there `imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);` by removing `imageloader` line

Comment: Nitin Misra i will update my code and posting can you please tell me